# Let Jenkins build a maven project from Perforce

Tags: maven, jenkins, perforce

I am trying to set up a Jenkins server to build Maven projects stored in a Perforce Depot but I am failing the setup of the Perforce plugin.

That's what I have (regardless of Jenkins):

- A running Perforce server with my Maven Project in a depot `//components/myjavaproject/main` (that's the path where the `pom.xml` is.
- A Perforce user `p4javabld` with a client spec called `p4javabld-cqm1`
- The client root is set to `D:\p4client\p4javabld`

When I set up a Jenkins project I set

- `P4PORT` to my perforce server,
- Username  to `p4javabld`
- Workspace to `p4javabld-cqm1`
- I did not allow Jenkins to create any new Workspace or Workspace View
- Client View type to `stream` with the stream `//components/myjavaproject/main`

On the config page I get *Unable to check workspace against depot* and *Unable to check stream against depot*

When I run a build it executes a

`p4 changes -s submitted -m 1 //p4javabld-cqm1/...`

which makes no sense I think. It seems then to scan the complete Perforce depot and seems not to concentrate on `//components/myjavaproject/main`

What is the configuration error?

Comment: I'm a little surprised you set the Client View type to "stream". Does Jenkins support Perforce streams? Since the problem seems to be with the client view, that's where I'd focus my attention.

Comment: I also tried with the *ViewMap* but I did not really figured out what to enter here. Again Jenkins started to get the complete visible workspace of the `p4javabld` user though I just want to sync and build a specific branch.

Comment: I am now trying with the Jenkins *P4 Plugin* (rather than the *Perforce Plugin*. But in this plugin again I did not find a place to configure the actual branch which should be synced and built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to let Jenkins build a Maven project from Perforce. I used the *P4 Plugin* instead of the *Perforce Plugin*. Then I configured a manual workspace with a workspace view to

`//components/myjavaproject/main/... //p4javabld-cqm1/...`

having the `pom.xml` in the root of `//components/myjavaproject/main/`

Comment: After I was running this a while I observed that the P4 Jenkins plugin (version 1.0.5) does not reliably sync all files.

Comment: There is now version 1.0.7 of P4 Jenkins and this works now for me.